# Django in processing extra method in views.py

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django, and having a difficulty soting out a problem. My code is processing extra method in views.py even without being called.Below is an example:-

1. When I am cliking on Home button on my page.
   Landing Page:
   [image: Landing Page]
2. I am being redirected to correct view method i.e., index.
   IndexMthod in views.py:
   [image: IndexMthod in views.py]
3. After loading the page my code is hitting another method edit content, without being called with a param favicon.io
   Concern Method
   [image: Concern Method] which is my concern.

Though it is not affecting my django app, but still it's annoying to see extra method being called everytime.

Please let me know, if I have done something wrong here or if any more info is required from my end. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your `get_entry()` function here? It could be helpful.

Comment: Below is defination of get_entry(),It is taking the query and checking if it exists on disk or not and returning result:
def get_entry(query):
    value=util.get_entry(query)
    return value